# I need to run electric past the dishwasher to the end of the peninsula cabinet

Tags: electrical, kitchens

We are replacing our kitchen cabinet layout and we are adding a peninsula. The peninsula is where our dishwasher will be with the plan of running plumbing and electric under the IKEA cabinets to the sink cabinet where there would be a dedicated outlet for the dishwasher. The toe kicks come off easily and will provide any needed access.

We know we need to add an outlet in at the end of the peninsula, but we are unsure of how electric will be able to get there. It is not an option to come up through the floor. We figure we could run conduit from the existing outlet behind the dishwasher, but we don't know if there is space behind a dishwasher to do this. We are having an electrician come in, but we need to figure this out before we finish planning the kitchen layout. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Do you already have two receptacle circuits for the kitchen as required in new code?  You will probably need to provision a second one if you don't have it already.  They make a lovely cable called 12/2/2 specifically for carrying 2 complete circuits from a panel.

Comment: We are getting the circuits all updated. We just want to make sure that we can run pipe to carry the wire past the dishwasher to the end of the peninsula. I assume there is space around the dishwasher to do this, but wasn't sure.

Comment: @Harper -- heck, in MC, you can get 12/2/2/2 xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's almost always an inch or two of space behind dishwashers. There isn't a standard depth, so the cabinets aren't built for that exact dimension.

It's usually fairly simple to pull dishwashers--two screws at the top or sides of the cabinet faceframe. Flooring set in front can make it challenging, though.

Comment: I agree +. unless mandated by local code for rigid I would use MC cable (in the back of the cabinet) easier to run than pipe because it is flexible and it provides protection for the wire similar to pipe for this type of location.